# Is it possible to assign a variable to two types?

Tags: java

Out of mere curiosity, is it possible to assign a variable to two types?

Since I don't have my technical terms straight in this matter, let me clarify a bit. Normally you would have a static and dynamic type:

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

Where the dynamic type has to inherit the static type:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {...}
```

But is it possible to ensure that the dynamic type extends/implements multiple types?

So that the `Dog` has to extend the `Animal`-class and implement an interface?

I'd imagine something like:

```
Animal [implements Happy] a = new Dog();
```

I'm quite sure it's just crazy talk, but is it possible? And if not, what's the closest alternative?

I'm thinking this only would be relevant in cases of ensuring a variable is of an interface you made yourself and a class that you cannot edit.

One way I can think of is determining it runtime by casting it every time you use it:

```
try {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Animal a = (Happy) new Dog();
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    //Is not of type Happy
}

//Using a method from the Happy-interface
try {
    ((Happy)a).smile();
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    //Is not of type Happy
}
```

Comment: You don't actually need to rely on casting, it would probably be easier and cleaner to use `a instanceof Happy` after defining a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible directly. You can think of some workarounds like:

```
abstract class HappyAnimal extends Animal implements Happy
```

And then use that type. Of course your classes must extend `HappyAnimal`, it won't work if they extend `Animal` and implement `Happy` directly.

Comment: I guess this is the correct answer. Nothing is lost, just a few lines of extra code and maybe a terrible OOD design, but that came with the idea in the first place. +1 and accepted answer in a few minutes, when possible.

Answer (score 3):

You could use generics by declaring a type parameter in either the class or the method you wanted to do the check in:

```
<A extends Animal & Happy> //put in class/method declaration

...

A a = new Dog();
```

This would allow you to do the type checking at compile time, without using any additional `abstract` classes.

Comment: Also a good answer. +1 - Although I'm giving the accepted answer to Tomasz for being quick. Unless one of you guys want to make a common answer?

Comment: Hmm, now that I think of it, shouldn't it be `<A extends Animal, Happy>` ?

Comment: @AskeBisgaard - Nope, that's the proper syntax for multiple bounds. Try it out.

Comment: I just tried it out and the `&` and it only works if the type on the right is an interface. The `,` works nevertheless. I wasn't familiar with the `&` so thanks for that. Anyway, this means you're right in this case. The following works: `<A extends MyClass1 & MyInterface1, MyClass2 & MyInterface2>` etc.

Comment: @AskeBisgaard - You're confused about the syntax. `,` is used to delimit additional type parameters, for example `<A, B>`. `&` is used to define multiple bounds - and yes the `class` type must appear first in the bounds.

Comment: A catch I found is that using the `,`s makes it impossible to use classes that aren't imported. E.g. java.util.List instead of just List and then adding an import.
EDIT: I may be confused, but I just tested that out, and it worked.

Comment: @AskeBisgaard - Check out [Oracle's generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) - that's going to be more productive than what you're doing right now. Not that you shouldn't play around in your IDE but it's good to read up on the basics first.

Comment: To others wondering: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html
At the very bottom. "To specify additional interfaces that must be implemented, use the & character, as in:

`<U extends Number & MyInterface>`"

Comment: I can't figure out how my test compiled, since, to my knowledge, there is no way a class can extend multiple classes, unless the classes are either subclasses or superclasses of each other. And if MyClass2 acts like the second generic type, then why doesn't it need an "extends" instead of an `&`? I'm very confused. I'm sure I just did something wrong.

Comment: @AskeB. - What compiled? Your `<A extends MyClass1 & MyInterface1, MyClass2 & MyInterface2>` didn't compile for me, as it shouldn't.

Comment: Yeah, nevermind on all that. I was a bit too fast to come to conclusions with my testing.